# How to share image with text in Facebook SDK in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I want to share a post on facebook with Image and text. I am using Facebook SDK and I am able to share Image, Now I want to share text with this image. How I can?

Here is the source code of sharing the image,

```
 let photo:FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()

    var message:String?

    let imageName:String = "Star.png"
    photo.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    photo.isUserGenerated = true

    let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    content.photos = [photo];


    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.fromViewController = self
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.mode = .native
    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Due to the abuse from some applications, Facebook has explicitly disabled the pre-fill option for the text by simply ignoring it.

> "You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the
>   following products, unless the user manually generated the content
>   earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for
>   Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message
>   parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description),
>   Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP."

More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill/?locale=it_IT).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook wont allow user to add text with image.

Integrate facebookshare sdk

```
@IBAction func facebookBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
  let shareImage = SharePhoto()
  shareImage.image = imageView.image //Image from your imageview
  shareImage.isUserGenerated = true

  let content = SharePhotoContent()
  content.photos = [shareImage]

  let sharedDialoge = ShareDialog()
  sharedDialoge.shareContent = content

  sharedDialoge.fromViewController = self
  sharedDialoge.mode = .automatic


  if(sharedDialoge.canShow)
  {
    sharedDialoge.show()
  }
  else
  {
    print("Install Facebook client app to share image")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 let sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = photo
photo.caption = "you title"

let content = FBSDKShareMediaContent()
content.media = [photo];
```

Comment: You cannot prefill the photo caption instead of the user. The user should do it according to Facebook Platform Policies (2.3).